# Api call after login msal authentication

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a problem that I can't find a way to solve.

I'm using `@azure/msal` authentication and after logging in I want the application to make a request to my `graph.microsoft.com` to get the user profile, with this user information, for example the `id`, will make another request to an api to obtain authorizations that this user, with this authentication information my application will control the menu and feed the `guards`.

This is all after the "login well is done" authentication before the app renders as this information must be in place for the build.

I've seen similar issues that get resolved with `APP_INITIALIZER` but in my case this flow is after `login`.

Any tips or ways that can help me?

Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  achieve the above requirement, Please check the below workaround which may help .

To make  Api call after login msal authentication we can setup as mentioned [**`here`**](https://www.prishusoft.com/blog/azure-ad-authentication-through-msal-to-connect-angular-app-to-asp.net-core-web-api.html) , using `“@azure/msal-angular”` library for AD authentication.

For more information please refer this [***MS DOC| Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from an Angular single-page application (SPA) using auth code flow.***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code)